# how to know that how many characters could be placed in one line?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout

I'm developing an android application and i need to know the number of characters that could be shown in one line to determine the number of lines of my string with some method .
How could do this ?
tanks a lot .

Comment: what are you talking about?? `Edittext`,`TextView`?????

Comment: TextView , but i use LayoutInflater so I can't use getlinecount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job for you (give or take a few mistakes from coding without an ide :-/ )

```
int countLineBreaks(final TextView view, final String toMeasure) {

    final Paint paint = textView.getPaint(); // Get the paint used by the TextView
    int startPos = 0;
    int breakCount = 0;
    final int endPos = toMeasure.length();

    // Loop through the string, moving along the number of characters that will
    // fit on a line in the TextView. The number of iterations = the number of line breaks

    while (startPos < endPos) {
        startPos += paint.breakText(toMeasure.substring(startPos, endPos),
                                   true,  tv.getWidth(),(float[]) null);
        lineCount++;
    }
    // Line count will now equal the number of line-breaks the string will require
    return lineCount;
}
```

..you get the idea ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Every character has its own width.
As any String which contains 10 characters is not same to another String which also contains 10 char.

u can set it by --> textView.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);

Monospace typeface works for making will regular char equal width.
Then u can do any stuff to get that how many characters could be placed in one line?

Comment: Well I use arabic string and use a font as typeface,how could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

set the [Typeface.MONOSPACE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#MONOSPACE) as geet suggested. then do the following

[Paint.measureText(String s)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText%28java.lang.String%29) returns the width of the String s. By using this you can get the required width of 1 character. And from the [View.getwidth()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getWidth%28%29) method you can get the width of the view. So from these two values you can calculate

Comment: I set my android:textSize = 4mm , is that meen every character has same size?

Comment: no it depends on typeface... if you don't use monospace then it can be different. For example the widht of 0 is bigger than the width of 1

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
int totalLine = textView.getMeasuredHeight() / textView.getLineHeight();
```