# Hide a view when textView is too long

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, textview, android-view

I'm looking to hide a view if my textview is too long and it starts to touch it, how would I go about doing this? So for example like this is okay:

[image: Normal Username length]

But when it's a long username and the length is nearer the time stamp I want to hide the timestamp, how would I go about doing this? Cannot think of it for the life of me!

**EDIT:** My current layout is like this

list_item_post.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/opBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/authorTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="34dp"
                android:layout_gravity="start|center"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/textview_corner_radius"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="18dp"
                android:paddingStart="18dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/postTriangle"
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_purple_triangle"
                    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dateTime"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/purple"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/morePostOptions"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_more"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/postText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagePost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance, can provide anything if you want to see it!

Comment: whats your current layout?

Comment: @BartekLipinski added

Comment: Maybe you can check if the view bounds touch? Create `Rect`s of the views, add the required space for one and check they `intersect`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way:
First determine how many characters make the string too long by trial and error or something.

Then use .length() to tell you the size of the string in the TextView

every time the TextView is updated you can use an if statement to say something like this.

```
Textview tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textv);
View v = findViewById(R.id.view1);

String str = tv.getText().toString();
if (str.length() > 9){
v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

I'm not sure what the rest of your layout is you may need to use layout_weight to help the rest of the layout adjust because "View.GONE" takes a view right out of the layout.  View.INVISIBLE makes the view just invisible but still exists.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Glad it worked !! Thanks for acknowledging it worked

Comment: by the way you can also reverse that by a similar statement.

if (str.length() <= 9 {
v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

Comment: actually a better way would be

} else {
v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

Comment: that would obviously make the view reappear if the length of the string dropped back below 9

Comment: @BilalMH and if user's phone has a font scaling set to a `>1.0` value or the screen is of a different size than yours, this approach falls apart completely.

Comment: yeah that's true the font scaling would ruin it

Comment: custom dpi would also ruin it now that i think about it.

Comment: by that i mean custom lcd density in build.prop or would it scale properly with that? i'm not sure i might be wrong maybe that would scale

Answer (score 1):

First you Find How many character place in single line on screen(https://stackoverflow.com/a/17378254/3416642) then check your Name String Length and compare both. e.g single line size 50 character and your Name String length 45 character  and Your date time text size 20 character  , if 45>(50-20) Then you can Hide  Date Time TextView.

Hope it will help you.

simple !

Answer (score 1):

(since [Jon Halls](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6468666/jon-halls) found my comment about other answers offensive, let me rephrase that and clarify few things)

1. I FIND other answers (present when I'm writing that), the accepted answer included, super-dirty.
2. They depend on eyeballing stuff.
3. They will fall apart when user is using a different device than the developer.
4. I believe you should use the following approach.
5. It does not depend on eyeballing.

Use a layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_timestamp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:maxLines="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**CAREFUL**: `layout_width`, `layout_weight`, `ellipsize`, `gravity` and `maxLines` parameters are really important. DO NOT change them.

Then add a simple `ellipsize` watcher to your timestamp `TextView`

```
timestampText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_timestamp);
timestampText.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Layout l = timestampText.getLayout();
        if (l != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < l.getLineCount(); ++i) {
                if (l.getEllipsisCount(i) > 0) {
                    timestampText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    return;
                }
            }
            timestampText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

**REMEMBER TO REMOVE YOUR `OnGlobalLayoutListener` WHEN YOU'RE DONE WITH IT!**

and here it is in action:

[image: in_action]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116495/discussion-on-answer-by-bartek-lipinski-hide-a-view-when-textview-is-too-long).

Answer (score 0):

I think you could get the position of your name TextView and position of your time TextView. Then check if name view has covered your time view.

Comment: How would I do that? Is it just a case of .getLength or .getPos? Or something

Answer (score 0):

you can check for the length of the textview and limit it as your requirement..

i.e.

```
 Textview textView=  //your textview

 if(textView.getText().length()>20){
               //hide your date
             dateView.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
            }
```

Comment: I don't want to limit the username TextView, I want to hide the date textview if the username one is too long